# Getting values from XML with conditions given using C#

Tags: c#, xml, checklistbox

I'm kinda new with using XML with C#.

XML CODE:

```
<LVL2>
  <Tables>
    <TBL_ID>1</TBL_ID>
    <TBL_Name>test1</TBL_Name>
    <MD_ID>1</MD_ID>
  <Tables>
  <Tables>
    <TBL_ID>2</TBL_ID>
    <TBL_Name>test2</TBL_Name>
    <MD_ID>1</MD_ID>
  </Tables>
  <Tables>
    <TBL_ID>3</TBL_ID>
    <TBL_Name>test3</TBL_Name>
    <MD_ID>1</MD_ID>
  </Tables>
</LVL2>

<LVL2>
  <Tables>
    <TBL_ID>1</TBL_ID>
    <TBL_Name>test4</TBL_Name>
    <MD_ID>2</MD_ID>
  </Tables>
  <Tables>
    <TBL_ID>2</TBL_ID>
    <TBL_Name>test5</TBL_Name>
    <MD_ID>2</MD_ID>
  </Tables>
  <Tables>
    <TBL_ID>3</TBL_ID>
    <TBL_Name>test6</TBL_Name>
    <MD_ID>2</MD_ID>
  </Tables>
</LVL2>
```

How do I insert to a checkedlistbox the text values from `tbl_name` that has an `md_id = 1` only. Here is my current code.

```
while (xmlReader.Read())
{
    switch (xmlReader.NodeType)
    {

        case XmlNodeType.Element:
            elName = xmlReader.Name;
            break;
        case XmlNodeType.Text:

            if (elName == "TBL_Name" && MD_ID == "1")
            {
                checkedListBox2.Items.Add(xmlReader.Value);
            }

            break;     
    }
}
```

I can't seem to figure out on how to get the text that has  `MD_ID = "1"` and output:

```
test4
test5
test6
```

Comment: The output you have posted in your question - Is it the expected output or the wrong output your current code is emitting currently?

Comment: Your XML isn't formatted properly. It doesn't have a root node. Please fix that.

Comment: those should appear as the output. Also Fixed my XML. Thanks

Comment: Sorry but your input xml still doesn't have a root node which is a must for any xml content to be valid. Any XML parser will give error while loading your xml data without any root node.

Comment: The `Tables` tags satisfying the criterion `MD_ID = "1"` have `TBL_Name` values as test1, test2 and test3. How can you expect test4, test5 and test6 and output then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the xml is not formatted properly. It should contain a root node and you missed the closing of a `<Tables>` tag. In the sample example, if you want to choose table names of elements having "MD_ID = 1" , the result will be:

> test1
>   test2
>   test3

If you want o/p as you mentioned, then the condition will be not equal to 1.
Here is the solution:

```
string xmlInput =  @"
    <root>
    <LVL2>
    <Tables>
     <TBL_ID>1</TBL_ID>
     <TBL_Name>test1</TBL_Name>
     <MD_ID>1</MD_ID>
   </Tables>
   <Tables>
    <TBL_ID>2</TBL_ID>
    <TBL_Name>test2</TBL_Name>
    <MD_ID>1</MD_ID>
   </Tables>
   <Tables>
    <TBL_ID>3</TBL_ID>
    <TBL_Name>test3</TBL_Name>
    <MD_ID>1</MD_ID>
   </Tables>
   </LVL2>
   <LVL2>
   <Tables>
    <TBL_ID>1</TBL_ID>
    <TBL_Name>test4</TBL_Name>
    <MD_ID>2</MD_ID>
   </Tables>
   <Tables>
    <TBL_ID>2</TBL_ID>
    <TBL_Name>test5</TBL_Name>
    <MD_ID>2</MD_ID>
   </Tables>
   <Tables>
    <TBL_ID>3</TBL_ID>
    <TBL_Name>test6</TBL_Name>
    <MD_ID>2</MD_ID>
   </Tables>
  </LVL2>
  </root>";

XDocument  xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlInput);

var filteredXML =
  xdoc.Descendants("root")
    .Elements("LVL2")
    .Elements("Tables")
    .Where(x => string.Compare(x.Element("MD_ID").Value, "1") == 0)
    .Select(x => x.Element("TBL_Name").Value)
    .ToList();

Console.WriteLine(filteredXML);
```

Refer following namespace:

```
using System.Xml.Linq;
```

Comment: Is it using LINQ feature of C#? Which namespaces do I need to import for using the classes you have mentioned in your code snippet?

Comment: You need to refer to `using System.Xml.Linq;`